# database independent Silverlight application - possible?

Tags: database, linq-to-sql, mvvm, design-patterns, independentsoft

I am developing my application in Silverlight with MVVM pattern support. Now I use Sql server 2008, but I am start thinking about in future use also Oracle and XML as storage for my data. I query with linq to sql.

It is pattern which I can use to completely automated and independent from database my application? Where I will only replace few parameters (for example in web.config) to change database, and I write code as little as possible in code behind... Maybe it's chance to connect and implement it in MVVM pattern ?

What do You think ?  I work out that in some db i will force to write queries in other ways(which will double or even triple code), cause db have other data types..so it's good idea to create so much independent app?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Entity Framework with RIA Services with Silverlight, you could potentially swap out your data layer to a different database provider very easily (provided it's one that supports ADO.NET Entity Framework).

Using MVVM is a good idea, but really unrelated to your database independence goal.  It's more of a pattern for structuring your application as a whole (which I recommend understanding), but the database access is really all part of your model layer in Model-View-ViewModel, so this isn't going to "help" with this aspect.

Comment: I thinking about use WCF service with data storage as Model. But I am starting learning about it, so maybe You advice me that this is better or RIA services? I know that one of ADO.NET features is every database support, but what about different data types for example: if I want select something from a table of every database type I should create a interface and implement it for every database i want to use? Cause in Oracle is data type which I don't have in SQL SERVER,and from them I will query with linq to sql, but from XML i use linq to xml, so I don't think that ADO.NET is so swappable...

Comment: XML won't be easy to use, but I'd highly recommend looking at RIA Services and Entity Framework.  WIthout this, you'll end up writing a HUGE amount of code to handle validation, change tracking, object mapping, etc - all of which would just be handled for you in an efficient, elegant way.

Comment: I want to avoid this Huge amount of code so i try with RIA. But I don't have any experience with it so can You tell my how to connect Silverlight application, MVVM and RIA? I only find that RIA can be ViewModel in MVVM, but from what i must start creating that project? First Silverlight projectm next create 3 folders for MVVM and inside ViewModel folder placed RIA project ?? o.O